# How to make a panel centered with minimum and maximum width in Visual WebGUI?

Tags: c#, web

I would like to make a panel with this behaviour in Visual WebGUI.

if window's width is smaller than minimal width of the panel, scrollbar appears.
if window's width is bigger than minimal width of the panel, the panel fill the width of the window.
if window's width is bigger than maximal width of the panel, panel remains at maximal width and sides of the window are empty.

Panel needs to be always in the center of the window.

How can I achieve that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a panel. 
Set the Dock = Fill for the panel.
Set the MinimumSize property of the panel to your desired width and height.

Now put any controls inside the panel. But set  the controls anchor property to None.

This way your controls will always be centered and scrollbars will be visible as you desired.

Comment: Well, there is a problem. You did not write about MaximumSize property, so this is not the answer. Anyway, some time passed and after checking source code, this cannot be done due a bug in VWG. But hey, thanks for respond.